# AChartEngine does not display the maximum chart value

Tags: bar-chart, achartengine

I am trying to display horizontal bar chart using AChartEngine.

In the bar chart, ChartValues should be displayed. (I am using XYSeriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true) in my code.)

Following is the rendered chart.

[image: horizontal bar chart]

As you can see, the maximum value is not displayed.
I think the length of the x-axis (about 140) region is not enough to display the region of maximum chartvalue.
Anyway, how can I display the maximum chartvalue in my chart?

Here's my code.

```
renderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#158aea"));
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.LEFT);       
    myRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    myRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
    myRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    myRenderer.setShowLabels(true);     
    myRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    myRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);     
    myRenderer.setXLabels(0);       
    myRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    myRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    myRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
    myRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.2);
    //myRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    myRenderer.setShowAxes(true);
    myRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    myRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);        
    myRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    myRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    myRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);        
    myRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);     
    myRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);        
    myRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);     
    myRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {60, -20, 80, 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the maximum Y axis value such as you will have enough space for the maximum value to be displayed.

```
myRenderer.setYAxisMax(150);
```

Comment: If I set the maximum value to be too high, the bar length would be too short to see (or cannot distinguish the difference between other non-maximum bars). I only need a small space that the maximum chartvalue can be displayed. Is there any smart way to do this?

Comment: Set the Y Max value to a smart value, 150 was just an example.