# Achart Engine Bar Chart the bars are thin if it has single series

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am using **Achart Engine** in my project, it works fine. However, I see that when I have only one series the bars become thin and aren't good, but if we have more than one series it is fine, I have looked into the source code and I see that in

```
drawSeries method they are calling getHalfDiffX(points, length, seriesNr);
```

and that method implementation is like this:

```
protected float getHalfDiffX(List<Float> points, int length, int seriesNr) {
    int div = length;
    if (length > 2) {
      div = length - 2;
    }

    float halfDiffX= (points.get(length - 2) - points.get(0)) / div;
    if (halfDiffX == 0) {
      halfDiffX = 10;
    }

    if (mType != Type.STACKED) {
      halfDiffX /= seriesNr;
    }
    return (float) (halfDiffX / (getCoeficient() * (1 + mRenderer.getBarSpacing())));
  }
```

It's because of this statement:

```
if (halfDiffX == 0) {
          halfDiffX = 10;
        }
```

How to solve this? I tried to post my issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/).

Comment: It's not about one series, it is about one single item in a series.

Comment: @Dan yes but how to fix this? is it a bug?

Comment: No, it's a feature :) There is an opened issue for that.

Comment: feature? how to justify that ? r u the author of this?

Comment: ok can you please help me to solve that? in my case

Comment: Does it matter who's the author?

Comment: No just asked you? it does matter to me i just wanted to know thats it , please dont mind

Comment: ok now how to solve this can you please help me

Comment: I'll do a fix and will let you know.

Comment: ok ok thanks will be waiting here only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a new `setBarWidth()` in `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` such as you can now set a constant width in pixels for the bars.

```
renderer.setBarWidth(100);
```

You can download a version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: can i know in which class having you made the changes?

Comment: Dan i will also upvote it ,sure thanks please wait i will just check

Comment: Dan i have give bar spacing as 0.3 but now there is no spacing

Comment: i had also done a work around for that just tel me if i am correct if(x.length > 1){
         multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.3f); // space between series
        }else{
         multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.7); // space between series
        } this is the one which i had made to fix for bar width

Comment: yes i agree, i really appericate that but i have set bar spacing as 0.3 but now there is no spacing? what am i missing?

Comment: Setting the constant bar width will ignore the spacing. Spacing between what, when you have one single item?

Comment: No i am dynamically adding the bars now if i have multiple bars the space between each item is not visible ? after setting the bar width

Comment: Setting the constant bar width will ignore the spacing.

Comment: Here is what I suggest you do. When you have only one item, you set the width, later when you add another one, set the width to -1.

Comment: ok just for curiosity i am asking as i said before i had made a wor around for this like if(x.length > 1){ multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.3f); }else{ multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.7);} was i correct ?

Comment: i just wanted to the bars to have common width no matter what the item no is like 1 or 10

Comment: and also i know this is a silly question to ask but still can i add a background image to chart ? because i see there is no way to set margin image or background image

Comment: No, you cannot add an image to the chart.

Comment: Ok Dan i have accepted your answer thanks , can i ask you some more questions ? if you dont mind?

Comment: Sure, ask other questions.

Comment: please have a look here i am also facing the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048709/achartengine-does-not-display-the-maximum-chart-value , i know this is bad to ask you what i want since i am giving finishing touches now please help me, my Ymax value is 50 i can make that to 60 so that it will display the chart value but the yaxis will be 20, 40 and so on but i need that to be 10,20,30...50 how to do this?, i cannot upvote since it says i need 20 rapo sorry :(

Comment: and also suppose in the 3 bars if i one among the bar is 0 say middle one then the bar will not be draw, but i dont want to show some space,since i am doing my intern they will see this and reject it so i am requesting you to help me

Comment: Please ask a separate question and explain it better because I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Dan please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788810/achartengine-does-not-display-the-maximum-chart-value-bar-chart

Comment: @user2056563 hey in which library u import the renderer.setBarWidth(100); i am not getting Barwidth in achartengine-1.0.0.jar can u please help i am facing same problem?